# Old TV show about a kid detective

Tags: story-identification, tv

I am trying to find an old TV show that aired in the 2010's I believe.

I vaguely remember it was about this boy who was super into history or something along those lines and falls into being a detective for some reason. One of the mysteries he solves ended with him finding the Russian satellite Sputnik. I think it was based on a college or high school campus.

I think it was on Nickelodeon or the Cartoon Network, I cant imagine it being on disney. If it was Disney it was Disney XD for sure. I also know for a fact that it was real people it was not animated.

Comment: Were there any fantasy or sci-fi aspects to it?\

Comment: Old TV show..... (from 2010s o_0 ) Hmm. that's barely recent... ;)  Ahh to be young and think ~8 years is old.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there don't appear to be any SF or fantasy elements here.

Answer (score 8):

This is [Unnatural History](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unnatural_History_(TV_series)):

> This series is centered on Henry Griffin, a teenager with exceptional skills acquired through years of globe-trotting with his anthropologist parents. But Henry faces his biggest challenge of all when he moves back to America to attend Smithson High School in Washington D.C., a place stranger than any he's ever lived before.

It fits all of your criteria:

1. Aired in 2010s
2. Teen into History
3. Takes place at a High School
4. Third episode (Sleeper in a Box) revolves around Spunnik 1.
5. Live action, but produced for Cartoon Network.

I watched the show when it first aired, and it was quite good. Although if I recall correctly (it's been a while), the fantastical or sci-fi nature of the mysteries he investigated (Fountain of Youth, cursed diamond, magic hammer, etc) eventually found a rational explanation by the end of the episode.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be [Encyclopedia Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopedia_Brown)?

Most well known as a book series, Leroy "Encyclopedia" Brown is a tween boy with an encyclopedic knowledge of minutiae who uses them to solve various crimes or mysteries.

The book series spawned a TV series of the same name in 1989, aired on HBO. The Wikipedia link above lists the episodes, and I have quoted them here:

> The series began with an hour-long special, "The Case of the Missing Time Capsule", and subsequent six episodes were 30 minutes long.

> 1. "The Case of the Missing Time Capsule" (hour long special first aired on March 2, 1989, to kick off series and aired over 200 times on HBO) "Idaville is celebrating its 100th birthday by opening a time capsule left by the town founder. But before anyone can discover what riches it contains, the capsule is stolen! When E.B. and his friend Sally investigate, they find no shortage of suspects.
> 2. "The Case of the Missing U.F.O." (Case #529) aired first on 3/9/90 . Something eerie is going on in Idaville when a flying saucer and flashing lights appear in the night sky. Encyclopedia Brown and his side-kick Sally interrupt their relaxing camping getaway to brave the unknown and uncover the mystery of the U.F.O.
> 3. "The Case of the Amazing Race Car" (case #524) first aired 3/16/1990 Davey looks like a sure winner in a funny car derby, that is, until someone steals his car. Encyclopedia Brown steps in to solve the mystery.
> 4. "The Case of the Ghostly Rider" (case #525) aired 3/23/1990 The ghost of the WildCat Kid has returned to haunt Old Glennville, can EB and Sally with a little help from Bugs Meany save the day?
> 5. "The Case of the Flaming Beauty Queen" (case #932) first aired 6/5/1990. Encyclopedia Brown investigates who set the fires in the library and whether the case of the hidden money is a scam or not.
> 6. "The Case of the Incredible Culpepper" first aired 7/10/1990. This episode does not seem to have been released to VHS. The big Idaville magic show is spoiled when a mountain lion belonging to The Incredible Culpepper is stolen. E.B. and Sally are immediately on the case and identify several suspects. With their typical detective skills they soon solve the crime and return the lion to Culpepper. The magic show finally entertains all the good folks of the town- Thanks to Encyclopedia Brown.)
> 7. "The Case of the Burglared Baseball Cards" (case #523) first aired 9/1/1990 Encyclopedia looks into the late night theft of a priceless collection of baseball cards.
> 8. "Encyclopedia Brown, The Boy Detective in One Minute Mysteries" released straight to video (This includes 5 of the Encyclopedia Brown stories from the books, "The Case of the Scattered Cards", "The Case of the Foot Warmer", "The Case of the Bitter Drink", “The Case of the Civil War Sword", and "The Case of the Great Merko". This was also released to VHS.)